# Can i play Google Drive videos with Jw-Player?

Tags: google-drive-api, jwplayer6

I want to play Google Drive videos with another player. (Mediaelement.js - JwPlayer..) because Google Doc. is using its own youtube player and I don't like it. Jw- player doesn't play these links.

Direct link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uSjTW2E4FGd1ozV3JIakE1NE0/edit?usp=sharing embedLink: "https://video.google.com/get_player?ps=docs&partnerid=30&docid=0B1uSjTW2E4FGd1ozV3JIakE1NE0&BASE_URL=https://docs.google.com/"

How can I play on of them in Jw-Player 6, Mediaelements or an alternative player?

Answer (score 0):

go to the google console, turn on the drive API, make an API key, then use the video source from a link like this:

```
var url = (id, key) => `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}?alt=media&key=${key}`;

....
<video>
<source src="url('YOUR_FILE_ID','YOUR_API_KEY')"></source>
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use https://googledrive.com/host/FOLDER_ID/Name.mp4 and replace FOLDER_ID with something like 0B5WjggiEiSjdNDFpMm5GdW8zR28 which you get from this link:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5WjggiEiSjdNDFpMm5GdW8zR28&usp=sharing

Make sure the folder is shared - Public and visible to all.

Comment: Also in this link is an example web page with a working embeded video with JwPlayer.